# There is no object type implementing interface `IAddress`. (HotChocolate.Types.InterfaceType<Grains.Models.Interfaces.IAddress>)

Tags: .net, graphql, hotchocolate

```
1. There is no object type implementing interface `IAddress`. (HotChocolate.Types.InterfaceType<Grains.Models.Interfaces.IAddress>)

   at HotChocolate.Configuration.TypeInitializer.Initialize(Func`1 schemaResolver, IReadOnlySchemaOptions options)
   at HotChocolate.SchemaBuilder.Setup.InitializeTypes(SchemaBuilder builder, DescriptorContext context, IBindingLookup bindingLookup, IReadOnlyList`1 types, LazySchema lazySchema)
   at HotChocolate.SchemaBuilder.Setup.Create(SchemaBuilder builder)
   at HotChocolate.SchemaBuilder.Create()
   at HotChocolate.SchemaBuilder.HotChocolate.ISchemaBuilder.Create()
   at HotChocolate.Execution.RequestExecutorResolver.CreateSchemaAsync(NameString schemaName, RequestExecutorSetup options, IServiceProvider serviceProvider, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at HotChocolate.Execution.RequestExecutorResolver.CreateSchemaServicesAsync(NameString schemaName, RequestExecutorSetup options, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at HotChocolate.Execution.RequestExecutorResolver.GetRequestExecutorNoLockAsync(NameString schemaName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at HotChocolate.Execution.RequestExecutorResolver.GetRequestExecutorAsync(NameString schemaName, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at HotChocolate.Execution.RequestExecutorProxy.GetRequestExecutorAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
   at HotChocolate.AspNetCore.HttpPostMiddleware.HandleRequestAsync(HttpContext context, AllowedContentType contentType)
   at HotChocolate.AspNetCore.HttpPostMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
   at HotChocolate.AspNetCore.WebSocketSubscriptionMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Routing.EndpointMiddleware.<Invoke>g__AwaitRequestTask|6_0(Endpoint endpoint, Task requestTask, ILogger logger)
```

Facing the above issue while implementing the graphql services with dot net web api.

```
 public class UserModel
    {
        public List<IAddress> Addresses { get; set; }
    }
```

This is query

```
public class Query
    {
        readonly IUserService _userService = null;
        public Query(IUserService userService)
        {
            _userService = userService;
        }

        public List<UserModel> Users => _userService.GetUsers();

    }
```

This is configuration

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        _ = services.AddMvc();
        _ = services.AddControllers();
        _ = services.AddSingleton(CreateClusterClient);
        _ = services.AddScoped<IUserService, UserService>();
        _ = services.AddScoped<Query>();
        _ = services.AddGraphQLServer().AddQueryType<Query>();
        _ = services.AddGraphQLServer().AddType<UserType>();
    }
```

I am using the above configuration, Model, Query and other stuff.

Comment: Could some one help me to solve this issue, i have tried by using the 
InputObjectType
ObjectType

as well! But no luck!

Comment: <PackageReference Include="HotChocolate.AspNetCore.Playground" Version="10.5.5" />
used this configuration.

Comment: <PackageReference Include="HotChocolate.AspNetCore" Version="11.2.2" />
  <PackageReference Include="HotChocolate.AspNetCore.Playground" Version="10.5.5" />